# How to automate wrapped web page using jsoup java

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm trying to automate a web page login using jsoup. I'm getting the html page as the response wrapped inside the body as following

```html
<body>
  <div id="pageRoot" class="webpage-wrapper"></div>
</body>
```

So I can't access required elements in html. How can I over come this?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'access' - what do you want to do?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't even remember why I asked this question. It was 2 years ago. :/

Comment: happens to me the same - no problem =) mind if i request deletion?